# Getting PowerReviews to load properly with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, magento

We are using PowerReviews within our Magento store as an over-ride to the standard Magento review system. We have it set up for the Category, Product, and Review pages and has been working fine for some time now.

Recently I added a module which brings AJAX reload functionality to the filtered navigation on the category page. i.e. I choose "Red" as a filter and the category page refreshes without reload with the proper products. This works fine when I have Power Reviews turned off.

When Power Reviews is on, the AJAX begins to load but then the page goes white and only the PowerReviews `<div>` tags are shown. When I look at the PowerReviews code I think I can see the reason:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  POWERREVIEWS.display.snippet(document, {
       pr_page_id : '49DAF4', 
       pr_write_review :    '/review/product/list/id/1907/category/111/#review-form',
       pr_read_review : txt, pr_snippet_min_reviews : 1});
</script>
```

Since the `POWERREVIEWS.display.snippet` is being called to 'document' what I think is happening is the AJAX load is happening, getting written to 'document' then the PowerReviews is happening and is also getting written to 'document'. Since this happens last, it hijacks the page instead of getting placed properly like it does on a normal load.

If I change 'document' to something like `document.getelementbyid('PWR')` and add a `<div id="PWR">` the snippet will not show on page. Is there a way I can target the output of `POWERREVIEWS.display.snippet` to something other than 'document' so the two scripts don't interfere with each other?

Comment: Might be useful to have a link to your site to get a better feel for what's going on here.  You've got reviews on your category pages or the JS isn't even rendering any reviews, but still conflicting on these pages?  Might also help to be able to inspect and play with the html/js.

Comment: Alas, I can not provide a link to the issue/error as it will massively break our live website and our development site is protected. To see how PWR is implemented without the AJAX you could look at http://www.americanmeadows.com/flower-bulbs/tulip-flower-bulbs . WHat we have on our category pages are the PWR Snippet which is delivered in a similar way was the reviews. On first load the snippets show up fine. On AJAX reload, the page will only show PWR content.I will see if I can set a test up somewhere.

Comment: From where I can get the API to fetch review details for products, Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PowerReviews actually provided an answer to this which works. They suggested using a JQuery delivery method to the DIV directly. Posting it here to help others.

> 1) Insert a JS include to a jquery library within the  section
>   (if you don't already):
>
> ```
> <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```
>
> 2) Use the write : function(content) syntax for the snippet function
>   call:
>
> ```
> <div id="pr_snippet_category_12345"> <script type="text/javascript">
> POWERREVIEWS.display.snippet({ write : function(content) {
> $('div#pr_snippet_category_12345').append(content); } }, { pr_page_id
> : '12345', pr_snippet_min_reviews : '1' }) </script> </div>
> ```

Comment: Can you put complete sample code. Also do you know if its possible to display rating inside javascript template? (I'm using mustache.js)